# Not a valid BCrypt hash in mysql

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am facing problem in comparing passwords from database and the provided password from body.
Please help.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
                    var newUserMysql = {
                       username: req.body.username,
                       password: req.body.password
                   };

                   db.query("SELECT * FROM dataa WHERE username = ?",[newUserMysql.username], function(err, rows) {
                         if (err)
                             return done(err);

                         if (rows.length) {
                             res.send("already a user")

                             console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(rows[0].password, newUserMysql.password));

                             if(bcrypt.compareSync(rows[0].password, newUserMysql.username)){
                               res.send("successfully logined")
                             }else{
                               res.send("password doesnt matched")
                             }

                          }
         });

})
```

Comment: your log compares with the password, but your if compares with the username?

Comment: I did that correction too then also same error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You have the compare method parameters in wrong order: first parameter should be the plain text password and second parameter the hash value. Also your if statement is comparing the password hash to username. The log row has this correct. I am assuming you have hash correctly in password field in the db.

The correct version after these changes would be:

```
...
console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(newUserMysql.password, rows[0].password));

if(bcrypt.compareSync(newUserMysql.password, rows[0].password)){
...
```

Please check syntax at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt.

Comment: Same problem is occuring now also.

Comment: Same problem is occuring after changes.

Comment: Based on the code in your suggested edit you still have parameters in wrong order. You need to provide the plain text password as the first parameter and already hashed value from database as the second parameter for compare-method. If this does not help, please check that the database value in field password is properly hashed value.

Comment: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: Excellent! Good that SO was able to help you. Please close this question because this is resolved now.

Comment: I would like your question in title and my answer be useful and findable in the future for other users. The question in title about invalid bcrypt hash is now solved, isn't it? If you experience other not related error, please consider solving it separately. If you need advice with asking questions, please check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions.